# How to prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{k}{(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}}=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}$?

Tags: contest-math, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to prove that $\sum_{j=0}^{k}{(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}}=(-1)^k\binom{n-1}{k}$?

LHS$=\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}...(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}$

$=\frac12\left(\binom{n}{0}-\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}...(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}+(-1)^{k}\binom{n}{n-k}...+ \binom{n}{n-2}-\binom{n}{n-1}+\binom{n}{n}\right)$

Is this right? How to proceed next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove this sum equal to an expression.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137110/prove-this-sum-equal-to-an-expression) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bj%3D0%7D%5E%7Bk%7D%7B(-1)%5Ej%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bj%7D%7D%3D(-1)%5Ek%5Cbinom%7Bn-1%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1). FYI, there are also questions here which ask specifically about using combinatorial approaches, e.g., [Combinatorial proof that $\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^j {\binom n j}=(-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k}$](/q/659653). ...

Comment: (cont.) Also, basically another duplicate is [Having trouble with a combinatorics proof](/q/214252). Finally, there are also AoPS threads, e.g., [Binomial](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2144972p15777573).